# How to sort an array of objects based on date

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects which I am attempting to sort based on the `createDate`.

```
[{
    "TestName": "com.DPProgram",
    "Test": {
        "createDate": "2018-02-15T17:17:10.000+0530",
        "effectiveStartDate": "1900-01-01T00:00:00.000+0530",
        "effectiveEndDate": "2200-01-01T00:00:00.000+0530"
    }
}, {
    "TestName": "com.DPProgram",
    "Test": {
        "createDate": "2018-02-22T15:00:11.000+0530",
        "effectiveStartDate": "2017-12-22T00:00:00.000+0530",
        "effectiveEndDate": "2018-12-23T00:00:00.000+0530"
    }
}];

data = data.sort(function(a, b) {
  data = data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a[data.createDate] > b[data.createDate]) 
  });
```

However it's not sorting

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/51545/

Comment: I edited the question to remove references to JSON and jQuery as neither are relevant to the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing the dates as strings. You need to instead convert them to Date objects before making the comparison.

Also your syntax of `a[data.bean.createDate]` is broken given the example. You need to access `obj.Test.createDate` instead.

Finally, don't use `alert()` for debugging, and especially not for any datatype more complex than a string. `console.log()` is more accurate as it doesn't coerce data types, and lets you traverse through the levels or objects/arrays.

With all that said, try this:

```js
var data = [{
  "TestName": "com.DPProgram",
  "Test": {
    "createDate": "2018-02-15T17:17:10.000+0530",
    "effectiveStartDate": "1900-01-01T00:00:00.000+0530",
    "effectiveEndDate": "2200-01-01T00:00:00.000+0530"
  }
}, {
  "TestName": "com.callidus.quotaDP.Tests.DPProgram",
  "Test": {
    "createDate": "2018-02-22T15:00:11.000+0530",
    "effectiveStartDate": "2017-12-22T00:00:00.000+0530",
    "effectiveEndDate": "2018-12-23T00:00:00.000+0530"
  }
}, {
  "TestName": "com.Foo",
  "Test": {
    "createDate": "2018-02-07T15:00:11.000+0530",
    "effectiveStartDate": "2017-12-22T00:00:00.000+0530",
    "effectiveEndDate": "2018-12-23T00:00:00.000+0530"
  }
}];

data = data.sort(function(a, b) {
  var aDate = new Date(a.Test.createDate),
    bDate = new Date(b.Test.createDate);
  return aDate > bDate ? 1 : aDate < bDate ? -1 : 0;

});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{
    "TestName": "com.DPProgram",
    "Test": {
        "createDate": "2018-02-15T17:17:10.000+0530",
        "effectiveStartDate": "1900-01-01T00:00:00.000+0530",
        "effectiveEndDate": "2200-01-01T00:00:00.000+0530"
    }
}, {
    "TestName": "com.DPProgram",
    "Test": {
        "createDate": "2018-02-22T15:00:11.000+0530",
        "effectiveStartDate": "2017-12-22T00:00:00.000+0530",
        "effectiveEndDate": "2018-12-23T00:00:00.000+0530"
    }
},{
    "TestName": "com.DPProgram",
    "Test": {
        "createDate": "2018-02-25T15:00:11.000+0530",
        "effectiveStartDate": "2017-12-22T00:00:00.000+0530",
        "effectiveEndDate": "2018-12-23T00:00:00.000+0530"
    }
}];
console.log(_.sortBy(data, 'createDate'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a sort function, you get two arguments that are elements of the data array you are operating on, and so you need to use them:

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.Test.createDate - b.Test.createDate;
});
```